# I want to create costume for my character but I dont know where to begin with modeling this specific one

Tags: modeling

I want to create this type of costume for my character. I would model it with Curves and other stuff, but I want it to be simulated. I have no idea where to start to be honest. I tried adding loops for the connection and use "Hooks", but when I move Armature those rings move but connected rope does not. The swimsuit was easy but the ropes...

My main goal is to make prepared character than i dont have to worry about breaking when I am going to make the animation.
[image: Refference Image of costume I want to create]